# check optional field to populate another field

Tags: scala

Is there any efficient way to remove the below if and else condition

```
object Currency {

  sealed trait MyConstants extends MyTrait[String]
  case object A extends MyConstants {val value ="abc"}
  case object B extends MyConstants {val value = "def"}

}

case class Test(name:String)
case class MyCurerncy(currency: Option[MyConstants])
 def check (name:String):Option[Test] ={.....}
 if(check("xyz").isDefined){
    MyCurerncy(Option(Currency.A))
 }else{
    None
 }
```

The method check return the `Option[Test]` .I need to populate `MyCurrency` based on the condition if Test is defined or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyCurerncy(Option(Currency.A))` is of type `MyCurerncy`.
`None` is of type `Option[Nothing]`. 
So

```
 if(check("xyz").isDefined){
    MyCurerncy(Option(Currency.A))
 }else{
    None
 }
```

will be of type `Any` (actually `Product with Serializable` but it doesn't matter). Are you sure you prefer to have `Any`?

If you prefer to have `MyCurerncy` i.e.

```
 if(check("xyz").isDefined){
    MyCurerncy(Option(Currency.A))
 }else{
    MyCurerncy(None)
 }
```

you can write

```
MyCurerncy(check("xyz").flatMap(_ => Option(Currency.A)))
```

If you anyway prefer Any you can write as you wrote or match

```
  check("xyz") match {
    case Some(_) => MyCurerncy(Option(Currency.A))
    case None => None
  }
```

Comment: why we are using flat map

Comment: @coder25
`map`, `flatMap`, ... allow to work only with the case when it's a `Some` inside `Option` and not `None`.

Comment: @coder25 https://alvinalexander.com/scala/collection-scala-flatmap-examples-map-flatten